# Form Field is null using Form recognizer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer

We are trying to extract data from a checkbox using the Form recognizer. We have a custom model where we extract 4 fields. All fields get extracted except one ("has_observations").

We used the analyze tab on fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net and it shows correctly for all the files we are trying to do OCR on.
[image]

```
    private static FormField GetField(this RecognizedFormCollection forms, string fieldName)
    {
        FormField field = null;

        foreach (RecognizedForm form in forms)
        {
            if (form.Fields.ContainsKey(fieldName) && form.Fields[fieldName] != null)
            {
                field = form.Fields[fieldName];
                logger.LogWarning("values is=" + field.ValueData.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }

        return field;
    }
```

The field is "Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.FormField" for "has_observations" label everytime and we have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of FormRecognizer SDK are you using? 3.1.1? You maybe calling different version from website vs from SDK.

If you are using 4.0.0-beta.X, by default it calls 2022-01-30-preview version of FormRecognizer APIs (see https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/4.0.0-beta.3/index.html), but based on the screenshot you are using 2.1. So, API results maybe different between versions.

A few other troubleshooting options to see exact URLs and responses for http traffic from FormRecognizer SDK:

- [Logging with the Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging), I.e. line below starts printing to the console each request/response.

  ```
  var listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger(EventLevel.Informational);
  ```
- Some information will be redacted in logs. Changes to ClientOptions below will show more data (see details in [Azure SDK diagnostics](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md)):

  ```
  var frOptions = new FormRecognizerClientOptions() { Diagnostics = { IsLoggingContentEnabled = true, LoggedHeaderNames = { "*" }, LoggedQueryParameters = { "*" }}};
  var client = new FormRecognizerClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential, frOptions);
  ```